# Calculating line integral on a vector field, help me find the mistake

Tags: polar-coordinates, line-integrals, greens-theorem

Alright, so, I have vector field: $F=[p(x,y), q(x,y)]=[y^3+e^{x^2}, x^3+{\tan}^2y]$. I need to calculate $\oint_Lpdx+qdy$, where $L: x^2+y^2+4y=0$. I transform it to $x^2 + (y+2)^2 = 4$, i.e. a circle with $r=2$ with origin at $(0,-2)$. The circle is "positively oriented", so I guess the integral should be going in counterclockwise direction.

The lecture from which this example assignment comes from introduces line integral and Green's theorem. Given presence of $e^{x^2}$, using the theorem is a must.

Thus: $$\oint_Lpdx+qdy = \iint_D (\frac{\partial{q}}{\partial{x}}-\frac{\partial{p}}{\partial{y}})dxdy = \iint_D(3x^2-3y^2)dxdy$$
I then try to change cooridnates to polar.
\begin{equation}
    \begin{cases}
      x &= R\cos{\varphi} \\
      y + 2 &= R\sin{\varphi} \\
    \end{cases}       
\end{equation}
After subsituting the circle equation, $R=2$. Then I define $D$ area:
\begin{equation}
  D =
    \begin{cases}
      r \in (0, 4) \\
      \varphi \in (\pi, 2\pi) \\
    \end{cases}       
\end{equation}
Back to double integral:

$$\int_\pi^{2\pi}\int_0^4(3(2\cos\varphi)^2-3(2\sin\varphi-2)^2)rdrd\varphi$$
Aaaaand, apparently after verifying with WolframAlpha, I have already failed here. **The answer after solving the double integral should be $72\pi$**. I get something like $-382-288\pi$ (might be inaccurate, writing from memory). Can you help me find the problem? I suspect I'm being dumb about the polar coordinate substitution, or $r$ has wrong range, or Jacobian is wrong

Comment: The limiuts for $\;r\;$ are wrong: the circle is $\;x^2+y^2=-4y\implies r^2=-4r\sin\phi\implies \dots\;$

Comment: I believe you're wrong, I transform it to $x^2 + (y+2)^2 = 4$ from $x^2+y^2+4y+4-4=0$. The $+4-4$ gives 0 but allows me to use quadratic equation, resulting in circle equation with coordinates. The circle has origin at $(0,-2)$ and radius of 2. Thus for polar coordinates, the circle spans from 0 to 2 times radius, that is 4.

Comment: Just sketch the domain, and you'll see that the length of $\;r\;$ depends directly on $\;\phi\;$ ...

Comment: And by the way: I keep on getting $\;48\pi\;$ as a result of that double integral...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limits for $\;r\;$ are $\;0\le r\le -4\sin\phi\;$ , so the integral's

$$\int_\pi^{2\pi}d\phi\int_0^{-4\sin\phi}3r^3(\cos^2\phi-\sin^2\phi)dr=\int_\pi^{2\pi}d\phi\int_0^{-4\sin\phi}3r^3(\cos^2\phi-\sin^2\phi)\,dr=$$

$$=3\int_\pi^{2\pi}\cos2\phi\,d\phi\,\,\frac14(-4\sin\phi)^4=192\int_\pi^{2\pi}\cos2\phi\,\sin^4\phi\,d\phi=-
48\pi$$

Comment: Oh my, you're right. Thank you so much!

Comment: Just one issue, you forgot to nullify the minus in $(-4\sin\phi)^4$ after raising to 4th power.

Comment: @bsqpt Excellent catch! Before that I was working with a power of $\;3\;$ ...and when I cleaned that up I forgot the minus sign. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After your transformation $x=x'$ and $y=y'-2$ since $dxdy=dx'dy'$ the integral becomes $\int\int_{D'}3(x^2-(y-2)^2)dxdy$ where $D': 0\leq r\leq 2$, $0\leq\theta\leq 2\pi$. Hence, the integral is
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^23(r^2\cos2\theta+4r\sin\theta-4)rdrd\theta=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^2(-12)rdrd\theta=(-12)(2\pi)(\frac{2^2}{2})=-48\pi$$
...

Another way: The circle in polar coordinates is $r=-4\sin\theta$ and so the domain is $D: 0\leq r\leq -4\sin\theta$, $\pi\leq\theta\leq 2\pi$. So, the integral is
$$\int_\pi^{2\pi}\int_0^{-4\sin\theta}(3r^2\cos2\theta)rdrd\theta=192\int_\pi^{2\pi}\sin^4\theta\cos2\theta d\theta=192(-\frac\pi 4)=-48\pi$$
where I took [some help](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral_%28pi%29%5E%282pi%29sin%5E4xcos2xdx).

Comment: That is wrong, I believe. Same mistake the OP did: r does *not* go $\;0\le r\le 2\;$ , but rather $\;0\le r\le-4\sin\phi\;$ . The circle is not centered at the origin. And of course the azimuth angle is between $\;\pi\;$ and $\;2\pi\;$ . All the circle is in the lower semiplane. The second way's wrong because you forgot the Jacobian.